# For Loop with Decimal in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to loop over decimal from 0.1 to 0.5 where the increment is 0.05. I was able to print the result with the codes below, but I would like to store the results in a data frame.

```
s <- seq(0.1,0.5, by = 0.05 )

for (i in s) {
print(data$ABC >= i)
}
```

I tried this code to try to store the results but I got a table that says "No data available in table". How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
s <- seq(0.1,0.5, by = 0.05 )
test <- vector("numeric")
for (i in s) {
test[i] <- (data$ABC >=i)
}
View(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the results in a list and then cbind them to combine.

```
result <- vector('list', length(s))
for (i in seq_along(s)) {
  result[[i]] <- data$ABC >= s[i]
}
result1 <- do.call(cbind, result)
```

However, you can do this with `sapply` as well which would be shorter.

```
result <- sapply(s, function(x) data$ABC >= x)
```

Comment: Thanks that works, is it possible to rename my column with the i  ?

Comment: I tried the below code to add the i to my column name but I cant seem to get the result I want.                                                                                                                        
  
`s <- seq(10,20, by = 1 )`
  `result1 <- vector('list', length(s))`
   `for (i in seq_along(s)) {`
  `result1[[i]] <- (allcrisis[,2:1081] >= s[i])`
  `for (i in colnames(result1)) {`
    `paste(colnames,i, sep = "_")`
  `}`
`}`
`result2 <- do.call(cbind,result1)`

Comment: You don't need to write two `for` loops. Copy my code as it is. After you do `result1 <- do.call(cbind, result)` Do `colnames(result1) <- paste(colnames(result), s, sep = '_')`. Sorry I wrote `i` by mistake in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, with this code I managed to change my column to A_1, B_2 , A_1, B_2 but is it possible to get A_1, B_1 and A_2, B_2  ?

Comment: I see that you asked a new question for that and received a satisfactory answer.